# pandas ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df`,

```
inv_id
d5
dd

a123
```

I like to convert `inv_id` into int and checks if its values is < 100,

```
df['inv_id'].str.replace(r'\D+', '').apply(int) < 100
```

but i got

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I understand that empty string cannot be converted into `int`, but I like to set empty strings as `False` no matter `inv_id` is empty string originally or after `str.replace` conversion into an empty string. so the results looks like,

```
inv_id    res
d5        True
dd        False
          False
a123      False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need using `to_numeric` rather than `apply(int)` ..

```
pd.to_numeric(df.inv_id.str.replace(r'\D+', ''),errors ='coerce')<100
```